# Расположенного или расположенной?

Tags: орфография

Конкретно на примере как правильно написать наименование объекта капитального строительства (ремонта)? Расположенного или расположенной?

Капитальный ремонт кровли здания Балчиклинского сельского клуба, **расположенного** по адресу: Республика Башкортостан, Бакалинский район, д.Балчиклы, ул.Центральная, 29.

Answer (score 2):

По указанному адресу расположено здание клуба, а не кровля. Поэтому РАСПОЛОЖЕННОГО:

Капитальный ремонт кровли здания Балчиклинского сельского клуба, (КАК**ОГО**?) расположенн**ого** по адресу: Республика Башкортостан, Бакалинский район, д.Балчиклы, ул.Центральная, 29.

Comment: А если бы было без "здания", т.е. просто "Капитальный ремонт кровли Балчиклинского сельского клуба"...?

Comment: Форма причастия была бы точно такой же. _Ремонт кровли клуба,_ (какого? — вопрос тот же) _расположеннОГО по адресу..._